# Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found - Fresh install issue

Tags: laravel

I just installed fresh installation of Laravel framework and I got error which I can't resolve.

I just follow the Laravel official instruction on http://laravel.com/docs/quick and the issue rise when I try to [Routing](http://laravel.com/docs/quick#routing)

I have no idea how to fix it and I can't find solution for this issue.

I installed Laravel **without** the Composer

*System info*

- PHP Version 5.4.4-14+deb7u8
- Linux morpheus 3.10.36+ #664 PREEMPT Mon
  Apr 7 14:01:14 BST 2014 armv6l
- Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

Thank you in advance!
Jan

[image]

Comment: When you say without composer do you mean via the installer or some kind of zip download and you literally don't have composer installed? Because my guess is that you are actually using composer (to some extent) and it's out of date, thus can't do PSR-4 autoloading (Monolog uses PSR-4) and hence the class not found error. Try doing `composer selfupdate` on the commandline.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this. Hang in there.

Comment: I just followed official info: First, download the Laravel installer PHAR archive. For convenience, rename the file to laravel and move it to /usr/local/bin. Once installed, the simple laravel new command will create a fresh Laravel installation in the directory you specify. For instance, laravel new blog would create a directory named blog containing a fresh Laravel installation with all dependencies installed. This method of installation is much faster than installing via Composer.
http://laravel.com/docs/quick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Solution : In your composer.json file, please change "minimum-stability" from "dev" to "stable" 
I had the same issue and did the trick 
Then run `composer dump-autoload`

This is a problem that arrived from Laravel 4.1.

Second solution : If that didn't solved the issue, you can try :

```
composer self-update
```

and then

```
composer update
```

Third solution : 
Try running :

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

Or use namespaces:

```
$log = new \Monolog\Logger('email');
$log->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('path/to/file.log', \Monolog\Logger::WARNING));
$log->addWarning('Some message.');
```

Comment: Hi, I didn't install Laravel via Composer, because I see that lots of user have troubles after update. But it seem I have to use it. Thank you for your advise ;)

Comment: Laravel is best installed under Composer. It's a main part of how Laravel works and how it keeps track of plugins and namespaces. You can start up learning composer from here : [composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)

Comment: Via Laravel it's working fine for me. I assume for normal installation (nor via Composer) user have to install all other dependencies manually like Monolog etc. Composer do it automatically. Fine for me. Thx a lot. Regards Jan